# react-native-navigation show lightbox without animation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation from Wix
How can I show the lightbox without animating. I want to show the lightbox immediately but It always spring
I cannot use the modal because the modal doesn't have transparent background
Best regards,

Comment: Modal on Android is transparent by default. To show a transparent modal on iOS, use `modalPresentationStyle: 'overCurrentContext'` https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/588#issuecomment-286697846